# Scrollview not scrolling when keyboard shown in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a textfield that when the user clicks on slides the keyboard up. Then the scrollview adjusts so you can read what you are typing.

My problem is that once that is so, I want to let the user to continue scrolling on the screen. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1:**

The scroll view's content size is not actually related to the size or position of the views it contains. If you want to change the size of the content view as well as the scroll view's content, you need to call two different methods.

```
 CGSize newSize;
 UIScrollView *scrollView;
 // assume self is the content view
 CGRect newFrame = (CGRect){CGPointZero,newSize}; // Assuming you want to start at the     top-left corner of the scroll view. Change CGPointZero as appropriate
  [  scrollView setContentSize:newSize]; // Change scroll view's content size
  [self setFrame:newFrame]; // Change views actual size
```

**Part 2:**

setNeedsDisplay marks the entire view as needing display. To cause it to display only the visible part, you need to use setNeedsDisplayInRect:visibleRect.
Assuming the view is at the top-left corner (its frame's origin is 0) and the scroll view does not allow zooming, the visible rect can be found using the scroll view's content offset and bounds size.

```
  CGRect visibleRect;
  visibleRect.origin = [scrollView contentOffset];
  visibleRect.size = [scrollView bounds].size;
  [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:visibleRect];
```

You could also choose to draw a part of the visible rect if only part changes.

And you can also look the following example :

[TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
 }



- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
     // To avoid keyboard hides the view
CGRect frame = self.view.bounds; 
if (capitalTextField.enabled ==YES) 
{
    if ([notification name]== UIKeyboardDidShowNotification ) 
    {

        frame.origin.y += 200;
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        frame.origin.y -= 200;
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES]; 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Increase height of the contentsize property of your Scrollview